# Determine if device is resting on a horizontal surface

Tags: android, ios, swift

I'm working on an Android and iOS application for which it is important to understand if the device is resting on a horizontal surface or not. Is there a way to verify it programmatically? I was thinking of using the accelerometer but the sensor data vary slightly even if the device remains stationary on the surface.

PS. I mean that the device must be physically supported on a surface like a table and not for example in the hand. This only interests me if the application is in use.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: What do you mean by "resting"? App in foreground? App in background? App inactive?

Comment: Do you just mean in the horizontal plane or actually in contact with a surface?